# CMake and Boost

Tags: boost, cmake, boost-thread

I've searched and found out that a lot of people have the same problem, but no solution exists.

I'm using CMake to generate Makefiles for MinGW and when compiling I'm getting an error:

```
CMakeFiles\boosttest.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.text+0x5e): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5boost6thread4joinEv'
CMakeFiles\boosttest.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.text+0x71): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5boost6threadD1Ev'
CMakeFiles\boosttest.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.text+0x88): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5boost6threadD1Ev'
```

This seems to be a linking problem, I get it. My CMake configuration is:

```
project(boosttest)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

include_directories(${boosttest_SOURCE_DIR}/include c:/boost_1_48_0/)
link_directories(c:/boost_1_48_0/lib)

file(GLOB_RECURSE cppFiles src/*.cpp)

add_executable(boosttest ${cppFiles})

target_link_libraries(boosttest libboost_thread-mgw46-mt-1_48.a)
```

First I tried using `find_package(Boost COMPONENTS thread)` and it was working the same way, so I thought to try to do this manually and I still get the same error.

Any insights on this?

I've compiled it for mingw using bjam and as a static link. Also tried doing:

```
add_library(imp_libboost_thread STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET imp_libboost_thread PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION c:/boost_1_48_0/lib/libboost_thread-mgw46-mt-1_48.a)
target_link_libraries(boosttest imp_libboost_thread)
```

And I still get the same error messages.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For mingw32 you may add definition `BOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB`. And linking with boost::thread will work. Also you may need `Threads` package (but i'm not sure, may be it needs only for *nix platforms).

Here is part of my CMakeLists. I copied it from project, which uses boost::thread, and compiles under mingw-gcc (and other compilers):

```
    set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS   ON)
    set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
    set(Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS "1.44" "1.44.0")
    find_package(Boost COMPONENTS thread date_time program_options filesystem system REQUIRED)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

    find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

    #...

    if (WIN32 AND __COMPILER_GNU)
        # mingw-gcc fails to link boost::thread
        add_definitions(-DBOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB)
    endif (WIN32 AND __COMPILER_GNU)

    #...

    target_link_libraries(my_exe
            ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}
            #...
        ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
    )
```

Comment: Adding BOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB fixed it for me. I've been scratching my head on this one for the last hour or so.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, this question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468681/problem-linking-to-boost-library-with-cmake-generated-project-file-for-msvc9) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623778/cmake-linking-to-boost-error-lnk2005). My best guess would be that you need the same resolution as in my answer to the [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468681/problem-linking-to-boost-library-with-cmake-generated-project-file-for-msvc9).

I would strongly recommend the use of find_package (Boost ) and take care with the auto-linking:

```
project(boosttest)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

# Play with the following defines
# Disable auto-linking. 
add_definition( -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB )
# In case of a Shared Boost install (dlls), you should then enable this
# add_definitions( -DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK )

# Explicitly tell find-package to search for Static Boost libs (if needed)
set( Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON ) 
find_package( Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread )

include_directories( ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

file(GLOB_RECURSE cppFiles src/*.cpp)

add_executable(boosttest ${cppFiles})

target_link_libraries(boosttest ${Boost_LIBRARIES} )
```

Comment: I've tried everything from those posts already, but also rechecked everything now and all the time I get the same error. It does find the library and sets the includes perfectly, but somehow it just won't link... I've also recompiled boost using `--build-type=complete` and tried to do a dynamic linking, and it still won't work...

Comment: In my case I had to add `find_package(Boost COMPONENTS thread system REQUIRED)` and   `target_link_libraries(<target>     ${Boost_LIBRARIES})` of course!