# What is the most basic example to run findboost.cmake

Tags: cmake, firebreath

I'm having issues preparing my firebreath visual studio solution which uses a cmake script. The problem seems to be with the findboost.cmake module. This is the error I'm getting:

```
CMake Error at C:/Users/chenning/cmake-2.8.8-win32-x86/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/F
indBoost.cmake:1200 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.50.0

  Boost include path: c:/boost

  The following Boost libraries could not be found:

          boost_date_time

  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
  directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
  Boost.
```

My boost root should be c:\boost.

What would be the most basic script or command line ( Windows 7 ) to test that module? I need to figure out the correct values for the parameters: BOOST_ROOT, BOOST_INCLUDE_DIR, and BOOST_LIBRARYDIR.

Thanks ahead,
Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see some example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254791/cmake-and-boost)

Also you can use boost debugging option:

```
set (Boost_DEBUG Yes)
```

I'm note sure, if this version of CMake is able to search Boost-1.50, so you can use

```
    set(Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS "1.50" "1.50.0")
```

This can helps to find recent versions of Boost

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have now set all kinds of variables but it's still not working. I have posted the output here: http://pastebin.com/6tiRftVW  For some reason I always end up with Boost_FOUND = FALSE. Can you figure out what's missing?

Comment: My problem was that I need to Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME=off so findboost.cmake can match the names of my libraries.

Comment: I see that headers of Boost searched correctly, so problem only is to find libraries (thread and so on). Maybe some compiled libraries is missing. Try to rebuild boost with option build-type=complete (or something like this)