# Linking errors with boost, VS2010, and CMake

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, opencv, boost, cmake

I have searched high and low for this answer. I have tried suggestions to similar problems posted on Stack and other sites. My toolchain consists of an x64 machine with windows 7, visual studio 2010, opencv 2.4, qt 4.8, and boost. I configure all of my projects using CMake, which finds all of these libraries and includes and creates my visual studio project. I have compiled two versions of boost, a 32-bit version build in the command line and placed in \boost\boost_1_47_0\lib\win32, and a 64-bit compiled in the Windows SDK v7.1 64-bit compiler and stored in \boost\boost_1_47_0\lib\x64. Everything in the project compiles fine with the exception of boost. I get a compiler error:

```
fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-1_47.lib'
```

As a reminder, CMake is handling all of my linking and it properly locates this lib and adds it to the visual studio project. I can verify this by looking at Properties->Linker->Command Line. Here, in addition to files representing other libraries, it has listed:

```
"C:\Tools\boost\boost_1_47_0\lib\x64\boost_filesystem-vc100-mt-1_47.lib"
"C:\Tools\boost\boost_1_47_0\lib\x64\boost_program_options-vc100-mt-1_47.lib"
"C:\Tools\boost\boost_1_47_0\lib\x64\boost_date_time-vc100-mt-1_47.lib"
"C:\Tools\boost\boost_1_47_0\lib\x64\boost_thread-vc100-mt-1_47.lib"
```

I can suppress this error by manually adding my boost\boost_1_47_0\lib\x64 directory to Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Dependencies. This compiles without error. However, when I go to run the application, I am met with a system error that tells me:

```
The program can't start because boost_filesystem-vc100-mt-1_47.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.
```

In this /x64 directory I have:

```
boost_filesystem-vc100-mt-1_47.dll
boost_filesystem-vc100-mt-1_47.lib
libboost_filesystem-vc-100-mt-1_47.dll
```

Any insight would be incredibly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is similar or equivalent to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6468681/417197 ?

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be the same problem as in the other question vis-a-vis automatic dynamic linking.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the runtime error:

Add the location of the dll(s) to the PATH environment variable.
For example on my machine:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;c:\users\chris\boost_regex-vc140.1.63.0.0\lib\native\address-model-32\lib
```

or copy the dll(s) to a directory already in the PATH

See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396